# GraphQL not supported by Spring boot 2.7.x and Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, java-17

getting below error while trying to execute grapgql 0.0.4 with spring boot 2.7.0 & higher and Java 17.

`Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [io/leangen/graphql/spqr/spring/autoconfigure/SpqrAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched`